# Change CSS of single 'LI' array element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript and jQuery.

I made a simple image slider and encounter an issue with jQuery.

I have the following html for my list of images:

```html
<div id = "slider-auto">
   <ul class= "slides">
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/one.jpg"/></li>
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/two.jpg"/></li>
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/three.jpg"/></li>
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/four.jpg"/></li>
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/five.jpg"/></li>
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/one.jpg"/></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to store the 'li' elements inside a variable(array) and change the CSS of a specific 'li' element using jQuery.

The following works fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $slideContainerMan = $('#slider-auto');
    $mySlides = $slideContainerMan.find('.slide');

    $mySlides[0].style.display = "block";
    
})
```

If I use jQuery to access the CSS of the first list element I get an error:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $slideContainerMan = $('#slider-auto');
    $mySlides = $slideContainerMan.find('.slide');

    $mySlides[0].css('display','block');
   
})
```

The above code produces '$mySlides[0].css is not a function'.

I am assuming this is not the correct way of accessing array elements using jQuery. 
How do I use jQuery to access 'li' elements singularly?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$mySlides[0]` returns the `li` element, and not the jquery object, thus you can't use the `css` function on it.
What you can do is use the jQuery constructor on that element `$(element)` or use the `first()` function to get the wrapped element:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $slideContainerMan = $('#slider-auto');
    $mySlides = $slideContainerMan.find('.slide');
    
    // option 1:
    $($mySlides[0]).css('display','block');
    
    // option 2:
    $mySlides.first().css('display','block');
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "slider-auto">
   <ul class= "slides">
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/one.jpg"/></li>
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/two.jpg"/></li>
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/three.jpg"/></li>
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/four.jpg"/></li>
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/five.jpg"/></li>
       <li class = "slide"><img src="Images/one.jpg"/></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: there is also an option 3: `$mySlides.eq(0)`

Answer (score 2):

The numeric properties on a jQuery object reference **DOM elements**, not jQuery objects.

If you want to call jQuery methods, you have to wrap the element with a jQuery object.

```
$( $mySlides[0] ).css(...)
```